# Who are the users "jicofo" and "jvb"?

Tags: login, 20.04

Today, when I rebooted my home computer after update, I saw, in addition to me, two new users: "jicofo" and "jvb". I certainly did not add these users. Who are they and why do I need them?

Comment: Both are part of Jitsi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You, or someone using your computer, has installed [Jitsi Meet](https://jitsi.linux.it/), a videoconferencing application. The user(s) are created with the application's installation. You need them to use the software.

Comment: I tried to remove jitsi-meet and got the reply "Package 'jitsi-meet' is not installed, so not removed". Does this mean that these two users are remnants from past installation, and I should just remove them manually?

Comment: Try running *sudo apt purge jigasi jitsi-meet jitsi-meet-web-config jitsi-meet-prosody jitsi-meet-turnserver jitsi-meet-web jicofo jitsi-videobridge2* (you may still have some of those installed, so may need to run them each individually). If that says nothing is found, and you still have the users, you can go ahead and delete them.